# Permitting access to a dynamically generated folder/file with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, .htpasswd

I have a site (running on a framework, so folders are virtual) with access blocked via .htaccess/.htpasswd, but I want to permit public access to one folder/file. I've tried all of the solutions suggested elsewhere but so far nothing has worked.

Here's the basic `.htaccess` contents:

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/.htpasswd
AuthName "MySite Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

I want to allow access to the URL `/api/user/create`. I have tried the following variations, all to no effect:

```
<Files "create">
Allow from all
</Files>

<FilesMatch create$>
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

SetEnvIf Request_URI "create" allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=allow
```

It seems like the filename `create` isn't recognised as a valid file, but I have no idea why the last one doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using virtual folders. `<Files *>` only takes effect for files on the disk. You should use the `<Location>` directive instead.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#location

Comment: I tried that as well, but it just starts throwing 500 errors. I don't think you can use Location (or Directory) inside `.htaccess`, only in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: You are right. It would bee the best using the httpd.conf anyway, if possible. You can just use it the same way, also for passwords.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to edit the `httpd.conf` file on my hosting.